# Extension of Riesz Representation Theorem for locally compact Hausdorff space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

Riesz representation theorem for positive linear functional is well known when underlying space is locally compact Hausdorff space. In this case, the measure we obtain is a positive measure. For arbitrary bounded linear functional, which is not positive, we will have signed measure. I got the proof for compact metric space in the text book 'Real Analysis' by Royden and now I want to extend it to locally compact Hausdorff space. Can anyone please suggest me any text book or other source for this? Thank you.

Comment: Rudin's real and complex analysis.

Comment: In Rudin, representing measure is complex measure.

Comment: See 2.14 for the positive case. For signed case, I think you can apply the complex case and find that the complex measure is indeed a signed measure.

Comment: okay, thank you @ John.